# Eclipse does not Highlght my JSP-File

Tags: java, eclipse, jsp, syntax-highlighting

I have a weird occurance and can't eclipse.

Somehow, Eclipse does not show the SyntaxHighlighting for one File, but for all the others:
[image: one File without Syntax Highlighting][image: The others with]

Did some else experience this problem once?
How can I fix this?
I allready tried closing and restarting Eclipse, but it ain't work!

Answer (score 2):

If only one file that having this problem, most likely you accidentally open the file with Text Editor. Eclipse will remember that last editor that you use to open the file. Right click on the file at explorer list, at Popup menu, select Open With > JSP Editor.